# Swift abstraction for enums with associated value

Tags: swift, generics

I have an enum with associated value `ConfigurationValue` that gets stored in a map. I have type specific getters for each possible enum value.

How do I minimize the code duplication between these getters

```
    enum ConfigurationValue {
        case bool(Bool)
        case int(Int)
        case string(String)
    }

    var map: [T:ConfigurationValue] = [:]

    public mutating func set(key: T, _ value: Bool) {
        map[key] = .bool(value)
    }

    public mutating func set(key: T, _ value: Int) {
        map[key] = .int(value)
    }

    public mutating func set(key: T, _ value: String) {
        map[key] = .string(value)
    }

    private func getValue(key: T) -> ConfigurationValue? {
        return map[key]
    }

    public func get(key: T) -> Bool? {
        guard let value = getValue(key: key),
              case .bool(let innerValue) = value else {
            return nil
        }
        return innerValue
    }

    public func get(key: T) -> Int? {
        guard let value = getValue(key: key),
              case .int(let innerValue) = value else {
            return nil
        }
        return innerValue
    }

    public func get(key: T) -> String? {
        guard let value = getValue(key: key),
              case .string(let innerValue) = value else {
            return nil
        }
        return innerValue
    }
```

Comment: Create a protocol to embrace Bool, Int, and String. Now make get and set generic on a type constrained to that protocol.

Answer (score 1):

I would not use protocols but instead I would add two methods in `ConfigurationValue` the first to create a configuration value and the other to get the inner value of a case.

```
enum ConfigurationValue {
    case bool(Bool)
    case int(Int)
    case string(String)

    static func with<Value>(value: Value?) -> ConfigurationValue? {
        if let value = value as? Bool {
            return .bool(value)
        }
        if let value = value as? Int {
            return .int(value)
        }
        if let value = value as? String {
            return .string(value)
        }
        return nil
    }

    func get<Value>(ofType type: Value.Type = Value.self) -> Value? {
        switch self {
        case .bool(let bool):
            return bool as? Value
        case .int(let int):
            return int as? Value
        case .string(let string):
            return string as? Value
        }
    }
}

let boolValue: Bool? = ConfigurationValue.bool(false).get() // Optional(false)
let intValue: Int? = ConfigurationValue.bool(false).get() // nil
let stringValue: String? = ConfigurationValue.bool(false).get() // nil

let boolConfiguration: ConfigurationValue? = .with(value: true) // bool(true)
let intConfiguration: ConfigurationValue? = .with(value: 42) // int(42)
let stringConfiguration: ConfigurationValue? = .with(value: "42") // string("42")
let doubleConfiguration: ConfigurationValue? = .with(value: 42.0) // nil
```

Now you can avoid boilerplate, let's say you have a struct `Foo`:

```
struct Foo<T: Hashable> {
    var map: [T:ConfigurationValue] = [:]
    
    mutating func set<Value>(_ value: Value?, forKey key: T) {
        map[key] = .with(value: value)
    }
    
    func get<Value>(key: T) -> Value? {
        guard let value = map[key] else {
            return nil
        }
        return value.get()
    }
}

var map: [String:ConfigurationValue] = [
    "bool": .bool(false),
    "int": .int(0),
    "string": .string("string")
]

var bar = Foo(map: map)
var bool: Bool? = bar.get(key: "bool") // Optional(false)
var int: Int? = bar.get(key: "int") // 0
var string: String? = bar.get(key: "string") // string
bar.set(true, forKey: "bool")
bool = bar.get(key: "bool") // Optional(true)
bar.set(42, forKey: "int")
int = bar.get(key: "int") // 42
bar.set("Hello World!", forKey: "string")
string = bar.get(key: "string") // Hello World!
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem like an enum is the right tool for the job here since you can get the same usefulness out of just casting the values (though admittedly you wouldn't get the benefit of exhaustive switch errors). If you're wanting to utilize generics to cut down on some of this duplication, I'd go with a wrapper around the map like so:

```
protocol Configurable {}
extension Int: Configurable {}
extension Bool: Configurable {}
extension String: Configurable {}

class ConfigurationMap<Key: Hashable> {
    private var map = [Key: Configurable]()

    func getValue(at key: Key) -> Configurable? {
        return map[key]
    }

    func setValue(_ value: Configurable, at key: Key) {
        map[key] = value
    }
}
```

Here `Key` would replace your `T` generic. To incorporate more data types, just extend the type that you want to use to be `Configurable`. The `ConfigurationMap` can also be a struct if you don't mind the mutating methods.

Comment: It's good, except it should be a generic subscript.

Comment: The enum is closed for extension, maybe that’s a requirement, that it must only ever be one of those 3 types? if so a protocol doesn’t do that.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift, this is not called a "map", but instead, a "dictionary". Type restriction can be achieved with a protocol, and explicit typing for retrieval.

```swift
public protocol ConfigurationValue { }
extension Int: ConfigurationValue { }
extension Bool: ConfigurationValue { }
extension String: ConfigurationValue { }
```

```swift
public struct ConfigurationDictionary<Key: Hashable> {
  private var dictionary: [Key: ConfigurationValue] = [:]
}

public extension ConfigurationDictionary {
  subscript<Value: ConfigurationValue>(key: Key) -> Value? {
    get { dictionary[key] as? Value }
    set { dictionary[key] = newValue }
  }
}
```

```swift
var configurationDictionary = ConfigurationDictionary<String>()

configurationDictionary["i"] = 1
configurationDictionary["i"] as Int? // 1
configurationDictionary["i"] as Bool? // nil

configurationDictionary["b"] = true
let b: Bool? = configurationDictionary["b"] // true
let i: Int? = configurationDictionary["b"] // nil
```